# Webpack build slower on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose, nodemon

I have a monorepo (using npm workspaces) in which I have currently a single sub-repo called backend, here is the folder structure

```
- package.json
- package-lock.json
-- packages/
--- backend/
---- src/
----- index.js
---- package.json
---- Dockerfile
```

packages/backend/Dockerfile simply build from the node latest version image and copy the required files from the monorepo and the service I want to run, as following :

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY package.json /
COPY package-lock.json /
COPY packages/backend packages/backend
```

and my docker-compose file is made to run the service with the root of the monorepo as a volume mounted as /usr/src/app/ within the container, as following:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: packages/backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    command: >
      sh -c "npm install --workspaces && npm run dev --workspaces"
```

the 'dev' npm script ran by the docker-compose run nodemon, who build the code under src/ using webpack and start the build (node dist/backend.js)

this setup works, it does what I want it to do but ...

when `npm run dev` is execute on the host, webpack takes around 2s to build the backend

when it's on the docker container, webpack takes around 20s to build it

So my questions are :

- From where that difference in duration comes from (something bad in my setup ?) ?
- Can I solve it (or at least reduce it) ?
- If yes, do you know how ?

Thank you !

Comment: You could try caching/layering in your node modules

Comment: You're re-running `npm install` every single time you start your application.  A better and faster practice will be to `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile, and delete both the `command:` override and the `volumes:` that hide the image content from the Compose setup.

Comment: I tried to move the npm install --workspaces in the Dockerfile, but I think as the volume is not mounted yet at that time, the sub-repo is not existing yet on the container, and the installation fails. The only way to make it works was to move it in the command: I have to use the volumes: because nodemon on the container has to detect changes that I do on my code on the host, to trigger the rebuild / restart.